# AWS SWF Respond Activity Task Completed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I can see in the SWF Management Console a Workflow has around 18 events, with the 16th event being my `ActivityTaskCompleted` event however whenever i poll for decisions i only get up to the 15th event so i never get to call `RespondDecisionTaskCompleted` with the decision type `CompleteWorkflowExecution` as such my workflows are always sitting in the Active state until they timeout.

The flow i'm using is from a PHP SWF git i found a while ago, i unfortunately do not have the link to it anymore though.

```
$response = $this->swf->PollForDecisionTask($opts);
$decision_list = self::_decide(new HistoryEventIterator($this->swf, $opts, $response), $this->swf);
if(count($decision_list) > 0)
{
    //Some decisions
}
else
{
    //No decisions
}
```

Where the HistoryEventIterator looks like so

```
public function __construct(Aws\Swf\SwfClient $swf_client, $original_request, $original_response) {
    $this->swf = $swf_client;
    $this->events = array();
    $this->event_index = 0;
    $this->next_page_token = null;
    $this->original_poll_request = $original_request;

    $this->_process_poll_response($original_response);
    $this->workflow_id = $original_response->get('workflowExecution')['workflowId'];
    $this->run_id = $original_response->get('workflowExecution')['runId'];
}

protected function _process_poll_response($response) {
    if ($response->hasKey("nextPageToken")) {
        $this->next_page_token = (string) $response->get("nextPageToken");
    } else {
        $this->next_page_token = null;
    }

    $next_events = $response->get("events");
    $next_events_object = new ArrayObject($next_events);
    $next_events_copy = $next_events_object->getArrayCopy();
    $this->events = array_merge($this->events, $next_events);
}
```

I have omitted error checking and functions of `HistoryEventIterator` that would not be called in this scenario. 
I have output the `next_page_token` of `HistoryEventIterator` and found it was always `NULL`.

Should the `RespondDecisionTaskCompleted` called from an Activity reach the decider? If so, what could be the cause for mine not? Surely it wouldn't be paging after 15 events, and simply not paging correctly.

I can verify that the Domain, Activity Task List, and Decider Task List are accurate as the Workflow shows up in the SWF Management Console, as does the decisions and the Activity (The Activity even has the status Completed) There is appropriate error checking and Try/Catch blocks and in no cases are there any exceptions.

Comment: Is your page size set to 15 perhaps? You can ask for them in reverse, perhaps you just need to do that?

Comment: I had considered it, but figured the`next_page_token` would have been set. I'll try to get the list in reverse, in theory if i can only get 15 entries at a time it would suggest that my `next_page_token` isn't being correctly set.

Comment: I set the reverseOrder to true, which in the script actually caused a decision loop however it was able to load over 100 events which is what i would expect. Once i corrected for the new order though (which i did by simple reversing the events list before i iterate over it) i was unable to get any more than 15 results again. I also undid those changes, and set my page size to 10. My event list stopped at 15 again and ActivityTaskCompleted was event 16. It does seem like the issue is specifically related to ActivityTaskCompleted.

Comment: So there are no other useful events in the data? It sounds like it might just be that SWF doesn't think you need to decide (on this pass) about that Completed. Can you try sending an empty DecisionTaskCompleted and see if the next time around you get it as the first event?

Comment: I ran two more tests, one where my activity did no work and just returned DecisionTaskCompleted. The event was 13, there was 17 total events, and my decider marked the workflow as Completed rather than it timing out. I also setup my decider to erroneously start activities until something said it was complete. It didn't get far, there were 24 events and the DecisionTaskCompleted was event 18. In every single case, except one, my event list that i retrieve always excludes the last 3 events.

Comment: The one case this didn't happen was the Workflow above, that only had 17 events but my Event history stopped at 15 (it also just so happened that because the DecisionTaskCompleted event was before that, it called the Complete Workflow)

Comment: I'm not sure you should focus too much on how many events there are "really" vs how many are in the events available to your Decider. SWF schedules the DecisionTask using whatever logic it wants (not sure what that is) and there's no guarantee that it will have all the events. Once you send a decision completion, you should get back another decision which includes those events (assuming they are actionable).